Gnome error: Extension “example@gjs.guide” does not exist
I am trying to learn a bit about development of GNOME Extension by following the GJS Getting Started page.
After completing the gnome-extensions create --interactive I try to enable the new extension with: gnome-extensions enable example@gjs.guide but I get the following error:

Extension “example@gjs.guide” does not exist

When I check the extensions folder for the new example extension it is there:
$ pwd
/home/xxxxxxxxxx/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
$ ll
[...]
drwxrwxr-x  2 xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx 4096 sep 14 12:24 'example@gjs.guide'/
[...]

In the extension folder:
$ pwd
/home/xxxxxxxxxx/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/example@gjs.guide
$ ls
extension.js  metadata.json  stylesheet.css

I get the default metadata.json:
{
  "name": "Example Extension",
  "description": "An example extension",
  "uuid": "example@gjs.guide",
  "shell-version": [ "46" ],
  "url": "https://gjs.guide/extensions"
}

where, apart from the shell-version, which is 46 in my case and is 45 in the guide, I do not get a url. So I have also tried to set it manually but without any different result. I also get the default extension.js:
/* extension.js
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
 */
import {Extension} from 'resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensions/extension.js';

export default class PlainExampleExtension extends Extension {
    enable() {
    }

    disable() {
    }
}

The third default file, stylesheet.css is mostly empty:
/* Add your custom extension styling here */

I am following the instructions for X11:
$ echo "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE"
x11

So everything seems to be correct but it still fails.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Eventually, doing step 3 for X11, of the Getting started guide first: ALT+F2 and restart did the trick:

Now the gnome-extensions enable example@gjs.guide works fine and I can continue my learning path.
